# NLS environment settings and Oracle Managed ODP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net-managed

We are migrating from the Unmanaged ODP.Net provider where we relied on that provider to read the NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT Window Environment variables.

Managed ODP.Net doesn't/can't access these Environment variables.  Is there a setting in the app.config file where one can tell Managed ODP.Net to use a particular NLS setting?

Comment: Have you tried using `OracleGlobalization` class?

Comment: @tpeczek - Yes, I was able to code a solution using the `OracleGlobalization` class that would read from a custom section of my App.Config file, and that works.  My question is really about whether or not there is a standard configuration option from Oracle in the `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` nodes?  I didn't find anything on Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/win.121/e17732/featConfig.htm#ODPNT8159) that seemed like it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my recent communication with the dev team via Oracle Support, there is no such option (v4.121.1.0).

Comment: so what's the proper way to configure NLS_SORT ?

Comment: I believe you can use the [OracleGlobalization](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/OracleGlobalizationClass.htm#ODPNT3113) class to alter the session's or thread's globalization settings. Since there have been a couple of new releases since, maybe there are other options, too...